# How to create a instance of a model if .find returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to use a text field to search for a user email and if it is found, create a membership. if it is not found i would like to create the user based on the email address.

**memberships/Index.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/logedinNav' %>
<section class="centered">
  <header>Team Settings</header>
  <section class="main">
    <aside class="blue_nav_aside">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><%= link_to_unless_current "General", team_info_path(:id => @team.id)  %></li>
                <li id="bluenav"><%= link_to_unless_current "Team Members", memberships_path(:id => @team.id) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to_unless_current "Tags & Categories",  %></li>
                <li><%= link_to_unless_current "Payments",  %></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
    <section class="inline_form">
        <%= form_for @membership do |u|%>
            <% if notice %>
                <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
            <% end %>
            <% if alert %>
            <p id="alert"><%= alert %></p>
            <% end %>

            <%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @membership %>

            <%= u.hidden_field :team_id, :value => @team.id %>
            <h1><span class="pictos pictos-form-h1">g</span>Team Members</h1>
            <%= u.text_field :user_email, :placeholder => "    To add a team member, enter their email here..." %>
            <%= u.submit "Invite", :class => "grey button" %>
            <section>
                <ul>
                    <% @memberships.each do |m|%>
                        <li>
                            <%= m.user.email %>
                            <% if m.team.admin_user_id != m.user_id %>          
                                <%= link_to(membership_path(m), :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this video?', :method => :delete, :class => "red_link") do %>
                                  <span class="pictos pictos-remove">-</span> Remove
                                <% end %>
                            <% end %>
                        </li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
            </section>
        <% end %>
    </section>
</section>
```

**Memberships_controller.rb**

```
class MembershipsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    @memberships = Membership.where(:team_id => @team.id)
    @membership = Membership.new
  end
  def create
    @membership = Membership.new(params[:membership])
    @team = Team.find(params[:membership][:team_id])
    @membership.user = User.find_or_create_by_email(:email => params[:membership][:user_email], :password => "pass", :password_confirmation => "pass")

    if @membership.save
      redirect_to memberships_path(:id => @team.id), :notice => "New membership created."
    else
      redirect_to memberships_path(:id => @team.id), :alert => "Fail."
    end
  end
  ....
end
```

**Membership.rb**

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  attr_accessible :user_id, :team_id
  attr_accessor :user_email

  validates_presence_of :user_id, on: :create
  after_create :set_team_admin

  def set_team_admin
    self.team.set_admin_user
  end
end
```

it works when the user is found but right now its not recognizing the `create_user` at all and skips to the Fail redirect.

UPDATE: this is the updated code with suggestions mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your membership instance doesn't know about the user_email parameter.

you could be using the rails dynamic finder methods http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Dynamic+attribute-based+finders for creating a user?
e.g. in memberships_controller.rb

```
def create
    @membership = Membership.new(params[:membership])
    @membership.user = User.find_or_create_by_email(params[:membership][:user_email])

    if @membership.save
      redirect_to memberships_path(:id => @team.id), :notice => "New membership created."
    else
      redirect_to memberships_path(:id => @team.id), :alert => "Fail."
    end
  end
```

Comment: I implemented what you said but it looks like it is only searching and not creating. the next comment will be the terminal output.

Comment: `...  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'nil@nil.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'nil@nil.com' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/memberships?id=2
Completed 302 Found in 125ms
`

Comment: I only tested it on the console, so maybe you have to add the following snippet to your membership model "accepts_nested_attributes_for :user". I cannot see, if your using fields_for in your form. If this still does not help, please update your Question by providing the params hash passed to your controller.

Comment: i added the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user` and updated all of my code samples so that you can see everything. thank you so much.

Comment: There we go: the problem is that you're having user-fields in your membership-form (e.g. :user_email). You have to surround this field by a <%= u.fields_for User.new do |user| %> <%- end -%> so you will get a  :user => {} object inside your membership-object in the params hash. Please see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for for further details

Comment: the problem was that my user wasn't passing the validations. I added some required info and it works great. `User.find_or_create_by_email(:name => params[:membership][:user_email], :email => params[:membership][:user_email], :password => "pass", :password_confirmation => "pass")`